# office 365 assign group to users

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365

i'm writing on behalf of a friend, that due to coronavirus has been "elected" as one of the global administraotr office 365 for school plan A1.
Unfortuantely he has been involved, once the users had been already created on the tenant.
they have more than  600 users  divided in teacher, student and external collaborator.
Unfortunately  the company who  created the accounts, did not create any AD group to divide them , but they :

1. follow this rule  when creating account :
    name.surname.xxx@schoolname.com  where 
   xxx is "d" if the user is a teacher
   xxx is "s" if the user is a student
   xxx is "ose" if the user is an external collaborator
2. The "title" (or role)  field contains "Teacher", "Student", "Collaborator" based on the user

He created 3 different AD Group "Teacher", "Student", "Collaborator", but in the user management , he cannot find a way to filter the users based on xxx@schoolname criteria , or sort/filter  based on title or role (that is an available display column).
If it would be available he could safely select part of the users and massively assign a group.

he has to select one by one , and ufortunatey the users are sorteb by name, so it is a big mess.

is there a way to apply the filter or sorting based on art of the account name ot title ?
is there a way with powershell to do it ?

thanks in advance

Fabrizio

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use Powershell script to make it.

Let's take Teacher as an example.

```
$users = Get-AzureADUser -All $true | Where-Object{($_.UserPrincipalName -like '*d@schoolname.com')}
foreach ($user in $users) {
   Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "{the ObjectId of the Teacher Group}" -RefObjectId $user.ObjectId
 }
```

It will find all the users "*d@jmaster.onmicrosoft.com" and add them into the Teacher Group.

Here are the cmd documents [Get-AzureADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0) and [Add-AzureADGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/add-azureadgroupmember?view=azureadps-2.0) for your reference.

Comment: I tried only the first row, directly in the powershell prompt, and don't know why it lists only  the first userpricipalname that has the correct domain d@schoolname.com, but starts with "A".   i tried to modify the command as  follow :   Get-AzureADUser | Where-Object{($_.JobTitle -like 'Doc*')} and it lists same results , but if i run following commad  Get-AzureADUser -Filter "JobTitle eq 'Docente'"  it will list all the users and not only the ones starting with a.  The where clause limits anything ? sorry but i've not understood how to format

Comment: @Grisu70 Try to use `$users = Get-AzureADUser -All $true | Where-Object{($_.UserPrincipalName -like '*d@schoolname.com')}`. `-All` If true, return all users. If false, return the number of objects specified by the Top parameter. I have also updated my answer.

Comment: Tks. I manage  to assign the group to all users.., and manage to update other attributes modifying the scripts.. many many thanks again

Comment: @Grisu70 I'm glad to know that this issue is resolved. You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.